# Is there a way to log output to a file when using OpenSSh in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, putty, openssh

I often use SSH to connect to my university's Linux Lab for school software development assignments. Until now, I've been using PuTTY to do this, but I want to switch to the SSH feature in Windows 10 since I've heard good things about it. One of the things I do a lot is testing my code with a program called testbed, which compares my program's output with the expected output. I like to look at the results as I try to fix any errors since it helps a lot with debugging, so I really like the logging feature available in PuTTY. It lets me log printable output, which I find easiest to understand after trying several of its other logging levels, to a text file, which I can keep open in any text editor as I work on my code. If it wasn't for this one feature, I would happily switch to Windows 10's built-in SSH feature. Is there a way to do this with that feature without manually selecting and copying everything each time?

Comment: Is `tee` available? `ssh user@remote.server.com | tee /path/of/log/file`

Comment: I don't know if that's available. I'm not very experienced with SSH, so I've never heard of it. I guess I could log on to my school's lab and try it.